# Clojure RethinkDB subscribe to a changefeed

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, rethinkdb

I am using the [Clojure driver for RethinkDB](https://github.com/apa512/clj-rethinkdb).
I want to get change feeds from a query. Here is what I have so far :

```
(defn change-feed [conn]
  (loop [changes (future
                   (-> (r/db "mydb")
                       (r/table "mytable")
                       r/changes
                       (r/run conn)))]
    (println "date : " ((comp :name :newval) first @changes)) ;;prints nil
    (recur (rest changes))))
```

It blocks in my REPL when called (which is normal). I then add data using the RethinkDB interface. It prints `nil` and I get the following error :

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$future_call$reify__6736  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:528)
```

What am I doing wrong ? I would like to be able to :

- take items from this future
- know also how many items I can take at once (if several are waiting)

*Note :* I plan to use [`manifold`](https://github.com/ztellman/manifold) to manipulate the result in the end, so any solution using it is completely fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need the future block there, the Cursor returned by the clj-rethinkdb library will block until it's ready.

You could also use a `doseq` instead of a loop which might be more natural.

I'm a maintainer of clj-rethinkdb, and we've got changes coming down the pipe to present a core.async interface and a new Cursor abstraction. If you want to use it early, checkout https://github.com/apa512/clj-rethinkdb/pull/55

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at that. Also thanks for making this. Note, I would have been happy with a core.async interface as well.

Comment: No how do you test in the REPL if the cursor blocks ?

Comment: You could open up a second REPL?

Comment: I suppose I could...  Waiting eagerly for you PR to be merged :) PS: in your answer, you mean "should *not* need" right ?